# Valid OpenGL context

Tags: opengl, glut

How and at what stage is a valid OpenGL context created in  my code? I'm getting errors on even simple OpenGL code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the posts on `comp.graphics.api.opengl`, it seems like most newbies burn their hands on their first OpenGL program. In most cases, the error is caused due to OpenGL functions being called even before a valid OpenGL context is created. OpenGL is a state machine. Only after the machine has been started and humming in the ready state, can it be put to work.

Here is some simple code to create a valid OpenGL context:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Window attributes
static const unsigned int WIN_POS_X = 30;
static const unsigned int WIN_POS_Y = WIN_POS_X;
static const unsigned int WIN_WIDTH = 512;
static const unsigned int WIN_HEIGHT = WIN_WIDTH;

void glInit(int, char **);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Initialize OpenGL
    glInit(argc, argv);

    // A valid OpenGL context has been created.
    // You can call OpenGL functions from here on.

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void glInit(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(WIN_POS_X, WIN_POS_Y);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello OpenGL!");

    return;
}
```

Note:

- The call of interest here is `glutCreateWindow()`. It not only creates a window, but also creates an OpenGL context.
- The window created with `glutCreateWindow()` is not visible until `glutMainLoop()` is called.