# Fl_Gl_Window flashes on creation

Tags: c++, opengl, fltk

I have some simple fltk code:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/gl.h>

class MyWin : public Fl_Gl_Window {
  public:
  MyWin(int x,int y, int w,int h, const char*l = 0) :
    Fl_Gl_Window(x,y,w,h,l)
  {
  }
  void draw();
  void resize(int X,int Y,int W,int H) {
    Fl_Gl_Window::resize(X,Y,W,H);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0,0,W,H);
    glOrtho(-W,W,-H,H,-1,1);
    redraw();
  }
};

void MyWin::draw() {
  ortho();
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    glColor3d(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(10,10,0);
    glColor3d(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(w()-10,10,0);
    glColor3d(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f(w()-10,h()-10,0);
    glColor3d(1,1,0);
    glVertex3f(10,h()-10,0);
  glEnd();
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
  Fl_Window win(500,500, "OpenGL");
  MyWin window(10,10,win.w()-20,win.h()-20);
  win.end();
  win.resizable(window);
  win.show(argc,argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

This example compiles and links perfectly for me on Windows 7 using mingw, but when I run it, it gets quite ugly. First the screen turns dark, and flashes with white. Then the screen is redrawn and my window appears. The same happens when I shut down the application.

I have tried to remove the drawing code, the same happens, then I removed the gl window from the outer window and it still happens. So it is not affected by the actual drawing. So my suspicion is that the opengl context creation causes this. Removing the creation of the gl window supports this hypothesis as the window now appears "quietly".

Does anyone know how I can get the Fl_Gl_Window to play nicely in windows?

Answer (score 0):

In the draw() function, I use

```
    if (!valid())
    {
        valid(1);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glViewport(0,0,w(),h());
        ortho();
    }
```

before anything else. I think it's an OpenGL function. If you put a printf statement in here, you will see that it gets called on the first draw and any resizing.

Perhaps it has something to do with this question: [Valid OpenGL context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364/valid-opengl-context) ?